# How to wait for system command to end

Tags: ruby

I'm converting an XLS 2 CSV file with a system command in Ruby.

After the conversion I'm processing the CSV files, but the conversion is still running when the program wants to process the files, so at that time they are non-existent.

Can someone tell me if it's possible to let Ruby wait the right amount of time for the system command to finish?

Right now I'm using:

```
sleep 20
```

but if it will take longer once, it isn't right of course.

What I do specifically is this:

```
#Call on the program to convert xls
command = "C:/Development/Tools/xls2csv/xls2csv.exe C:/TDLINK/file1.xls"
system(command)
do_stuff

def do_stuff
#This is where i use file1.csv, however, it isn't here yet
end
```

Comment: Please show us an example of your current code or explain the function. As far as I know, system calls are not just "offloaded", so I'm thinking you're offloading it somehow.

Comment: Does the system command return success? Assign the return value of system to a variable and then check its content. The system command should run synchronously.

Comment: When I assign the system(command) to a variable, it returns immediatly true. So that isn't an option either

Comment: Looking at the documentation for xls2csv it won't create file.csv it will create file1_Sheet1.csv (Or whatever the sheet is called)

Comment: @Ignace  did you ever figure out how to wait?  I don't mean did you check for the file... though that's cool. I mean did you figure out how to wait?

Answer (score 19):

Ruby's `system("...")` method is synchronous; i.e. it waits for the command it calls to return an exit code and `system` returns true if the command exited with a 0 status and false if it exited with a non-0 status. Ruby's backticks return the output of the commmand:

```
a = `ls`
```

will set `a` to a string with a listing of the current working directory.

So it appears that xls2csv.exe is returning an exit code before it finishes what it's supposed to do. Maybe this is a Windows issue. So it looks like you're going to have to loop until the file exists:

```
until File.exist?("file1.csv")
  sleep 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use threads:

```
command = Thread.new do
  system('ruby programm.rb') # long-long programm
end
command.join                 # main programm waiting for thread
puts "command complete"
```

Comment: How is using a secondary thread different from using the system command in the main thread? If the system command runs asynchronously in the main thread it will also in the secondary thread. So the join would finish immediatly while the system command is still running.