# `FileUtils.mv` fails if run directly after `system('openssl ...')` on a file this just created

Tags: ruby, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have this code:

```
...
system("openssl ... -in #{path.shellescape} -out #{tmpfile.shellescape} ...")
FileUtils.mv(tmpfile, path)
...
```

`path` is `"randomFile.mobileprovision"`, `tmpfile` is `"temporary"`.

The code should take the `randomFile.mobileprovision`, encrypt into a temporary file and then copy it back over the original file. When `FileUtils.mv` is executed both files should exist.

But I get an error like this:

```
Errno::ENOENT:
No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_rename - (temporary, randomFile.mobileprovision)
```

Strange.

During "debugging" I put a "puts `ls`" in front of the `FileUtils.mv` - and suddenly it worked!
Same when I put `sleep(0.1)` in front of `FileUtils.mv...` - it does *not* fail anymore.
What's going on?

---

This led me to believe that either `system` is not as synchronous as it should be (which I can't imagine...) or that `openssl` actually returns before the file is really written to the disk.

To check I changed the code to

```
system("openssl ...")
puts Time.now.round(10).iso8601(9)
puts `ls -l --time-style=full-iso #{Dir.mktmpdir}`     
FileUtils.mv(tmpfile, path)
```

This outputs the current time after `system` returned, then it gets the directory listing to see if and when the file was created.

My output:

```
2017-12-10T05:40:58.309145900+01:00

total 0
-rw-rw-rw- 1 sujan sujan 20 2017-12-10 05:40:58.291071400 +0100 randomFile.mobileprovision
-rw-rw-rw- 1 sujan sujan 65 2017-12-10 05:40:58.320572900 +0100 temporary
```

So `system` is done at .30.
The listing shows the `temporary` file was created only at .32!?

How is this possible?
How can I fix or workaround this?

---

Environment: `ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]` in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux, bash of Ubuntu) on Windows 10.

Comment: What happens if you use backticks instead of `system()`? e.g. ``output = `openssl ...` ``

Comment: Another thing to try: using the OpenSSL gem instead of shelling out to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but a better workaround than `puts` a directory listing:

> So it looks like you're going to have to loop until the file exists:
>
> ```
> until File.exist?("file1.csv")
>   sleep 1
> end
> ```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4539472/252627

I use it with `0.1` instead of `1`, an upper limit of 2 seconds and everything depends on not being on a Mac system:

```
  unless Helper.is_mac?
    count = 0
    # sleep until file exists or 20*0.1s (=2s) passed
    until File.exist?(tmpfile) || count == 20
      sleep(0.1)
      count += 1
    end
  end
```